# One or more screenshots have the wrong aspect ratio

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload screenshots (saved by the iOS Simulator) to iTunes Connect. Always getting this error message:

**One or more screenshots have the wrong aspect ratio. For more information, see the Developer Guide.**

I surely upload the proper size (640 × 1136 to 4-inch, etc)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That was because of UTF-8 letters in the screenshot file names — Russian letters in my case. (BTW these names are generated by iOS Simulator automatically.)

Just rename them to "1.png" and so on.