# A serious bug when uploading screenshots to iTunes connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

This is the second time i am writing here, after my first question was deleted .
I think this is a serious issue that more developers should be involve with .

Trying to upload screenshots to the iPhone 4.7(only) , you get the error :

```
The dimensions of one or more screen shots are wrong .
```

According to Apple the dimensions are :(from the docs)

```
750 x 1334 pixels for hi-res portrait
```

My images are jpeg, with the exact dimensions , i have also tried to change their names, recreate them, wait a few days, but nothing. 
**YOU CANT UPLOAD SCREEN SHOTS TO IPHONE 4.7 ONLY .**

Check out here, people already had this problem :
[Uploading screenshots to iTunes connect for iPhone 6 and 6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028272/uploading-screenshots-to-itunes-connect-for-iphone-6-and-6)

or here :

[One or more screenshots have the wrong aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821427/one-or-more-screenshots-have-the-wrong-aspect-ratio)

For me,none of the solution works, and i can't upload screen shots for few days now .

Is there anything i am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very strange solution i found to this problem, is that only photos taken from simulator screen shots are accepted for the 4.7 .
We have created many photos using illustrator and photoshop , that uploaded without no problem for the rest of the devices, seems that only the 4.7 has this problem .